# MessageBodyMember namespace overrides DataContract namespace in WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have following message contract :

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class fooResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://www.demo.com/serviceSchemaTypes-v1.4/")]
    public commonReturnType fooResponse1 { get; set; }
}
```

And the `commonReturnType` is a `DataContract` below :

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.demo.com/serviceSchema-v1.4/")]
public class commonReturnType
{
    [DataMember]
    public returnCode returnCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Generated WSDL file overrides namespace of `commonReturnType` to namespace of `public commonReturnType fooResponse1 { get; set; }`. After importing the generated WSDL file into another project, `commonReturnType` looks like this :

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.demo.com/serviceSchemaTypes-v1.4/")]
public partial class commonReturnType
```

Here, namespace should be `http://www.demo.com/serviceSchema-v1.4/`. Why the namespace is changing here and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is probably that you set this property:

`IsWrapped = false`

You can refer to the official documentation: [Using Message Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts) to make changes.